# How do you succinctly add two series together, but only adding the positive values?

Tags: python, pandas, addition

I have two series;

```
energy_dict['QLD'] = 

Timestamp
2017-04-27 00:00:00    523.720765
2017-04-27 01:00:00    512.180608
2017-04-27 02:00:00    519.076642
2017-04-27 03:00:00    516.329201
2017-04-27 04:00:00    525.150158
   ...                 ...
Freq: H, Name: QLD Total Energy (MWh), Length: 8760, dtype: float64
```

and

```
Incoming_Flow = 

Timestamp
2017-04-27 00:00:00    -8.961111
2017-04-27 01:00:00     9.503472
2017-04-27 02:00:00   -10.776389
2017-04-27 03:00:00     1.451389
2017-04-27 04:00:00   -10.388195
        ...               ...
```

Freq: H, Name: METEREDMWFLOW N-Q-MNSP1, Length: 8760, dtype: float64

I would like to add them together, but only when the second one is larger than zero. What is the best way to do this?

I am aware that I could do something like this;

```
Incoming_Flow[Incoming_Flow < 0 ] = 0
```

but I would like to be able to do it all in one line

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html) with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
s = energy_dict['QLD'].add(Incoming_Flow.mask(Incoming_Flow < 0, 0), fill_value=0)
print (s)
0    523.720765
1    521.684080
2    519.076642
3    517.780590
4    525.150158
dtype: float64

print (Incoming_Flow.mask(Incoming_Flow < 0, 0))
0    0.000000
1    9.503472
2    0.000000
3    1.451389
4    0.000000
Name: METEREDMWFLOW N-Q-MNSP1, dtype: float64
```

Or filter Series and use parameter `fill_value=0`:

> **fill_value** : None or float value, default None (NaN)
>
> Fill existing missing (NaN) values, and any new element needed for successful Series alignment, with this value before computation. If data in both corresponding Series locations is missing the result will be missing

```
s = energy_dict['QLD'].add(Incoming_Flow[Incoming_Flow > 0], fill_value=0)
print (s)
0    523.720765
1    521.684080
2    519.076642
3    517.780590
4    525.150158
dtype: float64
```

**Detail**:

```
print (Incoming_Flow[Incoming_Flow > 0])
1    9.503472
3    1.451389
Name: METEREDMWFLOW N-Q-MNSP1, dtype: float64
```

EDIT:

If performance is important, use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
s = pd.Series(np.where(Incoming_Flow < 0, 0, Incoming_Flow ), index=Incoming_Flow.index)
#if DatetimeIndex values are same in both Series 
s = np.where(Incoming_Flow < 0, 0, Incoming_Flow )
energy_dict['QLD'].add(s, fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`Series.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html) and [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
s = energy_dict['QLD'].add(Incoming_Flow.where(Incoming_Flow.gt(0), 0))
```

This is also ~18% faster than the `mask` solution if performance is important:

[proof]

```
s1 = pd.Series(np.arange(50000))
s2 = pd.Series(np.random.randint(-4, 10,50000))

%timeit s1.add(s2.mask(s2 < 0, 0), fill_value=0)
1.17 ms ± 25.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit s1.add(s2[s2 > 0], fill_value=0)
4.68 ms ± 289 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit s1.add(s2.where(s2.gt(0), 0))
988 µs ± 50.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: hmmm, I see typo in `s1.add(s2).where(s2.gt(0), 0)`, I think you want `s1.add(s2.where(s2.gt(0), 0))`

Comment: hmmm, If remove `)` get a bit worse timings (in my tests)

Comment: @jez what timings are you getting?

Comment: `%timeit s1.add(s2.where(s2.gt(0), 0))
956 µs ± 16.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)` and `%timeit s1.add(s2.mask(s2 < 0, 0), fill_value=0)
1.24 ms ± 50 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

Comment: OK, added new solution to my answer - `s1.add(pd.Series(np.where(s2 < 0, 0, s2 ), index=s2.index), fill_value=0)`

Answer (score 0):

Faster using numpy add and where

```
import numpy as np

qld = [523.720765, 512.180608, 519.076642, 516.329201, 525.150158]
flow = [ -8.961111,   9.503472, -10.776389,   1.451389, -10.388195]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(qld, columns=['QLD'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(flow, columns=['Incoming_Flow'])

s = np.add(df1['QLD'], np.where(df2['Incoming_Flow'] > 0, df2['Incoming_Flow'], 0))

print(s)

0    523.720765
1    521.684080
2    519.076642
3    517.780590
4    525.150158
```

Timings:

```
s1 = pd.Series(np.arange(50000))
s2 = pd.Series(np.random.randint(-4, 10,50000))

%timeit s1.add(s2.where(s2.gt(0), 0))
890 µs ± 58.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit np.add(s1, np.where(s2 > 0, s2, 0))
367 µs ± 6.82 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Yes, but it is possible only if `DatetimeIndex`es are same in both DataFrames. If not, need my last answer.

Comment: Yes true.  It is not clear if the two series in the question were originally from the same dataframe.